# What's the right way to install an appropriate package containing <signal.h> on a Linux Mint VM?

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, package-management

I have Linux Mint installed on a VM: `Linux jonathan-mint-virtual-machine 3.5.0-43-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 17:33:43 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` I tried to compile something that uses`<signal.h>`, but it couldn't find it.

What can I install so that a compiler looking for basic header files will find it?

Comment: As Mint is still a Debian derivative, I also like to search for missing files using http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine what package to install you can use this tool.

```
$ apt-file search <file>
```

Searching for a vaguely named file, `signal.h` is going to be tricky though. You'll likely need more information than just the name.

#### Example

Here are the 1st 6 occurrences.

```
$ apt-file search /signal.h | head -6
avr-libc: /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/signal.h
c-cpp-reference: /usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kdevelop/reference/C/MAN/signal.htm
dietlibc-dev: /usr/include/diet/signal.h
dietlibc-dev: /usr/include/diet/sys/signal.h
elks-libc: /usr/lib/bcc/include/bsd/signal.h
elks-libc: /usr/lib/bcc/include/signal.h
```

You can get the list of unique packages using this form.

```
$ apt-file search -l /signal.h | head -6
avr-libc
c-cpp-reference
dietlibc-dev
elks-libc
fp-docs-2.6.0
frama-c-base
```

#### C headers

Since you've specified that you'd like to install the package that includes `<signal.h>`, you're likely looking for an include file, `include/signal.h`.

```
$ apt-file search -l include/signal.h 
elks-libc
libc6-dev
libc6-dev-armel-cross
libc6-dev-armhf-cross
libklibc-dev
libnewlib-dev
libroot-core5.34
mingw-w64-i686-dev
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev
mingw32-runtime
msp430-libc
python-pycparser
python3-pycparser
```

So you're likely looking for this package, `libc6-dev.

Comment: Since the example line is `<signal.h>`, you want to `apt-file search include/signal.h`. In this case it's part of `libc6-dev` which is also part of `build-essential`.